# jQuery UI datepicker disabled option not being recognized by Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, this, jquery-ui-datepicker, rxjs5

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker in an Angular 2 application, and it works fine with one exception.  My application has a list of radio button options that, when any one of them is checked, sets a variable called serviceTypeChosen to true (variable is initially false when app loads).

I want the datepicker to be disabled until the user checks one of the radio buttons, making serviceTypeChosen true.  I have a separate service that builds an order for the user, and in the datepicker component I'm subscribing to a method of the service that tracks the building of the order as the user goes through the various stages of the app.  I know that the serviceTypeChosen variable is being switched from false to true when the radio button is checked and that my subscription to the service recognizes when the variable's value changes because the console logs I have inserted behave the way I expect them to, notifying me that the datepicker is disabled until a radio button has been checked, and notifying me that it's enabling the datepicker once I check a radio button.  However, as it stands with my current code the datepicker is disabled regardless of whether or not a radio button has been checked.

I've determined that the 'if' portion of the statement works properly.  If I set the disabled property of the datepicker to false, the datepicker is disabled.  If I set it to true, it works.  The issue lies in the 'else' portion of the statement.  The console log works as expected by the datepicker's disabled property is not affected.  I'm baffled.

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Component } from
'@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from 
'@angular/forms';

import { OtrixService } from '../otrix.service';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'otrix-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss']
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('readyDate') dateInput: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private otrixService: OtrixService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.otrixService.getStagedOrder().subscribe((order) => {
      if (!order.serviceTypeId) {
        console.log('Service type not yet chosen. Datepicker
        disabled.');
        jQuery(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({disabled:
        true});
        console.log(this.dateInput.nativeElement);
      } else if (order.serviceTypeId) {
        console.log('Service type chosen. Enabling datepicker.');
        jQuery(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({disabled:
        false});
      }
    });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    jQuery(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({
      minDate: new Date(), // custom settings
      maxDate: '30d',
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      onSelect: (datePicked: boolean) => { // when user picks a date...
        let readyDate =  
        jQuery(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker('getDate');
        this.otrixService.setReadyDate(readyDate);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the datepicker enable/disable is being called correctly?  It could be an issue with that.

Comment: @chrispy Yes, I know the call is correct, because if I take out the line of jQuery code that disables it and put that on a line by itself outside of the if statement it works.

Comment: I noticed that if I use a traditional function instead of an arrow function, I get an error that says 'cannot ready property nativeElement of undefined'.  That's what leads me to believe it's an issue with 'this'...like it's not being properly selected or something.

Comment: Hmm, I feel that the scope should be properly preserved in your example...

Comment: @chrispy I just edited my post.  See added paragraph.  I'm puzzled.